# Google Maps API and Offline Maps

Tags: android

I have a small android app project in mind and it will use the Google Maps API. I'm wondering if it is possible to save an offline map specifically for my app to use, or if I could access an offline map that is downloaded onto my google account through my app. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible for 3rd party apps to control how maps data is being handled, including off-line usage. It may change in future but for now, you are out of luck.